# GMP setting last digit to zero

Tags: rounding, mathematical-optimization, gmp

I’m looking for fastest way to set last digit of positive number `l` declated as `mpz_t` to zero. I didn’t find the function could to this already. For example `6531489321483` should be changed to `6531489321480`.

Comment: How about diving your number by 10 and then multiplying by 10? E.g. Let `int x = 1234`, then `x / 10` gives `123`. Now multiplying, we obtain `123 * 10 = 1230`.

Comment: So with `mpz_t`, we have `mpz_div_ui(x, x, 10); mpz_mul_ui(x, x, 10)` (not tested)

Comment: I think for the actual division you will want to use `mpz_tdiv_q_ui`. See the [docs](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Division) for more details.

Comment: `x-x%10` seems possibly faster than `x/10*10`. Do make sure you define what should happen for negative numbers.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, doesn't modulo require division and multiplication, along with subtraction (I.e. `a % b = a - (a / b) * b`)

Comment: @JosephWood: A look at the GMP source might be needed to confirm, but I'd expect `x % 10` to be computed (e.g., using `mpz_fdiv_ui`) in a single pass over the limbs of the mpz.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, while that may be true, it appears that division followed by multiplication is faster.

Comment: Yep, nice. I'd still hazard a guess that the mod-and-subtract approach is asymptotically faster (looks like the number you're testing is only a couple of limbs in size), but OTOH we don't know what size numbers the OP wants to apply this to.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, good point. I was messing around with implementing a more complicated example with random `mpz_t` values via one of the random generators provided by `gmp`, but opted not to for clarity.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, thanks for pointing this out. I've never thought about `gmp` operations in this way before. That is, how many limbs are requires for a particular operation. As you can tell from my previous comments, my first thought was "number of operations". Your few comments here have really changed the way I look at this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

It appears that subtraction and modulo is the superior method for zeroing out the last digit with `mpz_t` types. Just as @MarkDickinson and @MarcGlisse pointed out, the asymptotic behavior greatly favors using `mpz_tdiv_r_ui` (or `mpz_fdiv_r_ui`) over `mpz_div_ui` followed by `mpz-mul_ui`. My original benchmarks were on relatively small numbers (25 digits). I retested on a 175 digit number and the `sub_mod` method was nearly 40% faster.

```
Test value: 1234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789
Result with div_mul: 1234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456780
Result with sub_mod: 1234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456780
time with division followed by multiplication: 6.145656
time with subtraction and modulo: 4.413998
```

And with a 350 digit number we see that `sub_mod` is around 85% faster:

```
Test value: 12345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789
Result with div_mul: 12345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456780
Result with sub_mod: 12345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456789123456789876543212345678912345678987654321234567891234567898765432123456780
time with division followed by multiplication: 10.256122
time with subtraction and modulo: 5.522990
```

It should be noted that whether we use `mpz_tdiv_r_ui` or `mpz_fdiv_r_ui`, the results were almost identical.

Since the `sub_mod` method was only marginally slower with smaller numbers, it seems reasonable to only use this method for all cases.

It would be nice to tests this on different compilers. I'm currently using `clang 5.0.1`.

### Original

Benchmarks on my machine show that division followed by multiplication is faster than finding the remainder via modulo operator and subtracting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <gmp.h>

void div_mul(mpz_t x) {
    mpz_tdiv_q_ui(x, x, 10u);
    mpz_mul_ui(x, x, 10u);
}

// Maybe this could be simpler?
void sub_mod(mpz_t x, mpz_t y) {
    // N.B. mpz_mod_ui is equivalent to mpz_fdiv_r_ui. Changed to 
    // mpz_tdiv_r_ui for consistency with div_mul.
    mpz_tdiv_r_ui(y, x, 10u);
    mpz_sub(x, x, y);
}
```

Main:

```
int main() {

    mpz_t testVal;
    mpz_init(testVal);
    mpz_set_str(testVal, "1234567898765432123456789", 10);
    gmp_printf("Test value: %Zd\n", testVal);
    
    mpz_t x;
    mpz_t y;
    
    mpz_init(x);
    mpz_init(y);
    
    mpz_set(x, testVal);
    div_mul(x);
    gmp_printf("Result with div_mul: %Zd\n", x);
    
    mpz_set(x, testVal);
    sub_mod(x, y);
    gmp_printf("Result with sub_mod: %Zd\n", x);
    
    const int limit = 100000000;
    const double checkPoint0 = (double) clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
        mpz_set(x, testVal);
        div_mul(x);
    }
    
    const double checkPoint1 = (double) clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    const double time_div_mul = checkPoint1 - checkPoint0;
    printf("time with division followed by multiplication: %f\n", time_div_mul);
    const double checkPoint2 = (double) clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
        mpz_set(x, testVal);
        sub_mod(x, y);
    }
    
    const double checkPoint3 = (double) clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    const double time_sub_mod = checkPoint3 - checkPoint2;
    printf("time with subtraction and modulo: %f\n", time_sub_mod);

    mpz_clear(testVal);
    mpz_clear(x);
    mpz_clear(y);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Test value: 1234567898765432123456789
Result with div_mul: 1234567898765432123456780
Result with sub_mod: 1234567898765432123456780
time with division followed by multiplication: 2.941251
time with subtraction and modulo: 3.171949
```

I suspect that one of the reasons that the latter method is slightly slower is that 2 variables are needed as complicated multi operations on the same line are not accessible in the `C` api. If we could use `gmpxx`, we could write `x - x % 10`.

Another thought as to why the first method is faster, is that the `div_mul` involves two operations with unsigned integers while the `sub_mod` method involves an operation with an unsigned integer followed by an operation with `mpz_t`.

I tried to get this reproduced on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) but could not get `gmp.h` loaded. I opted to implement a [similar benchmark](https://ideone.com/QOC8iY) with type `long long int` just for fun. You will note the presence of `volatile` and that the limit is one billion instead of one hundred million as seen above. The `volatile` was need to keep the for loop from being optimized away.

Comment: On my computer, both have roughly the same running time (second one slightly faster). mpz_mod_ui is mpz_fdiv_r_ui, you may want mpz_tdiv_r_ui to match your other version. This function also returns an unsigned long, which you can plug in mpz_sub_ui. Your test number is very small.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, you are spot on.... I retested with a huge number and `mpz_tdiv_r_ui` and the results are clear. The `sub_mod` is faster. I'm updating the post right now.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the number to a string and changing last character wouldn't be the fastest way?

Comment: Not asymptotically, at least: the number is stored in binary, and the base-conversion algorithms from binary to decimal are worse than linear complexity. (The naive base-conversion  method is quadratic time, but GMP almost certainly does something substantially better than quadratic but still worse than linear here).